# r - Adaptive division in time intervals for a set of observations

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe with animal observation linked with time and I need to assign them to different groups depending if the obs are 10 minutes apart from each other. It is not ideal to utilize a fixed 10 mins division of time though.
My df looks like this:

```
             DateTime Total_Adults Site    Species  Group_equal_int Group_ideal
  2016-05-28 18:29:14            1   1A wildebeest                1           1
  2016-05-28 18:29:53            1   1A wildebeest                1           1
  2016-05-28 18:30:02            1   1A wildebeest                1           1
  2016-05-28 18:37:56            1   1A wildebeest                1           1
  2016-05-28 18:45:03            1   1A wildebeest                2           2
  2016-05-28 18:50:24            1   1A wildebeest                3           2
  2016-05-28 18:50:40            2   1A wildebeest                3           2
  2016-05-28 18:58:52            1   1A wildebeest                3           3
  2016-05-28 18:59:25            1   1A wildebeest                4           3
  2016-05-28 18:59:41            2   1A wildebeest                4           3
```

The observation are considered independent if 10 minutes apart, otherwise the two obs are counted as of the same animal.

An easy solution would be to divide the time series in 10 mins brackets starting from the first obs;

```
interval <- seq.POSIXt(from = min(df$DateTime), to = max(df$DateTime), by = 600)
df$Group_equal_int <- findInterval(df$DateTime, vec = interval)
```

I prefer not to; this division is coherent as long as the observation are spaced less that 10 mins apart. Once the successive obs is more than ten mins apart from the previous, there is the possibility that the time interval chosen in the first place falls in the middle of a set of obs that should be considered a single obs (less than 10 mins between the first and the last) and count that as two obs. I show that happening in the Group_equal_int compared to the group_ideal.

I would need to divide the time of my dataset in a way that account for this, yet I have no idea how to make the starting point of the 10 mins breaks to re-set every time two obs are further apart than 10 mins.

any idea?

Comment: Assuming the data frame is ordered by time, why not just calculate the time between the successive observations and assign them to the same group if it is less than 10 mins?

Comment: That would result in grouping a long series of obs in a single group is they are less than 10 mins from each other, even if from the "start" to the "end" of the series more that 10 mins goes by (that should result in more than one group)

Comment: In your example of ideal group, shouldn't group 2 also include observation at 18:50:40?

Comment: But I agree with Anamaria's suggestion. If an additional observation is added at 18:00:30, less than one minute after the last one in your example, it will be considered as an independent animal when using your definition. So the split in groups of 10 minutes seems a bit arbitrary in this example...

Comment: @Pierre It's true, it is intrinsically arbitrary and has limitations. Yet, it has been calculated in a peer reviewed paper in the same environment for the same species with the same technique and with a huge dataset, so it is as good as you can get I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, with a good old for loop:

```
df$difftime <- c(0, diff(df$DateTime)/60)

df$group <- 1
time_in_group <- 0
for (i in seq.int(2, nrow(df))) {
    time_in_group <- time_in_group + df$difftime[i]
    if(time_in_group < 10)
        df$group[i] <- df$group[i-1]
    else {
        time_in_group <- 0
        df$group[i] <- 1 + df$group[i-1]
    }
}
```